# Not able to reach managed server over ssl (https)

Tags: ssl, https, weblogic11g

I am able to reach my weblogic console over https connection but when I try to launch developer console that is setup as a managed server in the weblogic domain, it fails. However, I can reach the dev console over http port without any issues.

I checked the validity of certs installed my keystore and configured to enable ssl port in managed servers. I am not sure what I am missing here. Please advice if I am missing any additional checks/setups.

```
For eg, 
http://<XXX.cname.com>:9005/console - works on http
https://<XXX.cname.com>:9009/edq - does not work on https
```

I verified from console that ports are right and ssl ports are enabled.

Comment: what type of error are you getting ? Connection reset ?

Comment: Nope..it just says site not reachable. Logs show no error messages either. Just wondering if the port on managed servers is listening to any connection requests. Any suggestions on how I can check it!!

Comment: try nc -zv -w 10 XXX.cname.com 9009

Comment: It responds with: connection to <cname> port 9009 succeeded!!

Comment: could you also try "openssl s_client -connect cname:9009" and check if ssl/tls certificate info is displayed?

Comment: Cool..I think this gave me a direction. I find the following message in output:verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain.                I need to dig further though to get a better understanding.  Thank you very much for the guidance!!